# How can I access all test in suite in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Is there any possible way to access list of all test execution in current test suite during it's execution. In my case I have one scripts with 20 test cases. Each of them has some tags. When starting Robot I can ask it to execute only test with specific tags. I'd like to know which test were chosen by Robot form my script. I know that such info is provided to listener. Can I access it for example in suite setup during execution?

Thanks
Pawel R.

Comment: Could you explain your scenario a little more?  From what I understand you want to know which test cases from a suite will execute when you provide certain tags?  Wouldn't a simpler option be to just do CTRL+F and find the number of tests you use the tag in if you want a test case count?  Otherwise what's the problem with executing and checking the log to see what test cases executed?

Comment: As I gather, you want to access the selected test cases programmatically, i.e. assign to a variable runtime and manipulate it in the code (presumably, in the same test suite), right?

Answer (score 1):

Today, you can create a small [library that will act as a listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.1.2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-acting-as-listener) as well that can do a runtime check which tests have been selected. I am using Robot Framework 3.1.2 here.

It basically needs two things

1. A `start_suite` method from the [listener API](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.1.2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-2). This method will be invoked at the start of every suite or until it returns an explicit `False`. When invoked a parameter called `attributes` will be passed to it. This parameter is a dictionary, that has the following key/value pair, `"tests: Names of the tests this suite has as a list. Does not include tests of the possible child suites."`.
2. A keyword that will log all test names and could be used from `Suite Setup`.

lib.py

```py
from robot.api import logger

class lib(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'    # define library scope
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2        # select listener API
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 0.1
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self    # tell the framework that it will be a listener library
        self.attributes = None

    def _start_suite(self, name, attributes):
        self.attributes = attributes
        
    def log_suite_test_names(self):
        for test in self.attributes['tests']:
            logger.info(test)
        

globals()[__name__] = lib
```

test.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library    lib
Suite Setup    log suite test names

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    [Tags]    A
    No Operation
    
Test 11
    [Tags]    A    B
    No Operation
    
Test 111
    [Tags]    A    B    C
    No Operation
    
Test 1111
    [Tags]    A    B    C    D
    No Operation
```

Results when launched like: `robot --pythonpath . --include C test.robot`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could always try doing a dry run using

```
--dryrun
```

This should be nice and quick to see what is run when you look at the report.html

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dry-run

Answer (score 0):

If usage of RF itself was not obligatory and the OS was *nix-related I would go for

```
grep -E -B 1 "( )(tag|tag2)( |$)" test.robot
```

where:

`-E` initiates regex syntax of grep,

`-B 1` prints out one preceding string relative to matched (which gives us Test Case names).

You could also add `|grep -v Tags` to only keep the strings that contain Case names.

If you have some other stuff between a `[Tags]` section and a Case name just increase `-B %index%` a little and put more stuff after `|grep -v`.